# Can we speak of "Microsoft himself"? - "... the man who brought Microsoft to Nepal is now at Microsoft himself!"

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

I found this on a facebook comment.

> Great to see the man who brings Microsoft to Nepal is now at Microsoft himself!

Besides *brings*, is this grammatically correct?

I feel that *Microsoft himself* is incorrect. But I don't know.

Comment: I think this question should stay open. OP has identified the specific source of his confusion, though it may take a little reading between the lines to get inside his head and see exactly why he's confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from *brings* (which as you suggest should probably be *brought*), the sentence is grammatically OK.

The referent of *himself* is not *Microsoft* but *the man ...*. Putting the emphatic *himself* at the end of the sentence is common— it puts even more emphasis on that final word. For instance, this is entirely natural:

> The contractor who built this prison is now incarcerated there himself.

It's only problematic here because in writing your eye moves backward, and the first noun it encounters is *Microsoft*. It takes a beat or two to realize that *himself* cannot refer to a place, and then move past *Microsoft* and *Nepal* to *the man*. In speech this problem doesn't arise, because you parse with the ear, not the eye, and a sentence leading to the detached *himself* has a different pitch contour than one which ends on a collocation like *Microsoft itself*.

Comment: A comma after '*Microsoft*' could help to wrap up that clause ("at Microsoft") and bring "*himself*" closer to "*man*".

Comment: @VictorBazarov I would resist that comma, which intrudes an improper disjunction. The only real solution in writing is to move *himself* after *now*; but that wrecks the rhythm and turns a colloquial sentence into a very formal one. In fact, the ambiguity scarcely exists for a native-speech reader, who would never conceive that *himself* could refer to MS.

Comment: I have no problem with **himself**, but the sentence is weird to me. I can get a sentence like *the man who brought Microsoft to Nepal is now at Microsoft himself*, but what does "*Great to see*" at the beginning of sentence?!!!

Comment: @Ahmad Again, this is very ordinary colloquial use: *It is* is omitted at the front.  "It is great to see [that] the man &c". For a technical description, check out John Lawler's post at ELU on [*conversational deletion*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/24489).

Comment: @Ahmad That it is nice to witness this event/hear this news.